# Using v2 token endpoint still giving v1 token: Azure Active Directory

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-authentication, azure-identity, azure-app-registration

I created a new app registration and set scopes for Application.Read.All and User.Read.All. I exposed one custom scope as access_as_user. Using v2 token endpoint still giving v1 tokens that is the main issue now.

v1 token endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/token`

v2 token endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Both endpoints giving tokens with same version i.e, **version 1.0** Why so?
If I registered multitenant applications then it is giving tokens with **version 2.0** with both endpoints.

My requirement is to get v2.0 tokens for single tenant applications. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one single tenant application and granted **API permissions** like below:

[image]

When I checked the **Manifest** of this application, *accepted token version* is null as below:

[image]

I generated the **token** for custom scope using `v2.0` token endpoint via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), token version is **1.0** as below:

[image]

To get **v2.0** token, you need to change your application's Manifest like below:

[image]

When I generated the token again and decoded it, I got the token version as **2.0** as below:

[image]

In your case, change the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to **2** in your Manifest's file and generate the token again.

Comment: Did you see fixed token right away after changing accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 or you had to wait. I changed it and it still ver 1 in the access token.

Comment: For me it was also an incorrect scope, which seems to default to a v1 token and old sts issuer. Scope api://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/.default -> this one gave me a v2 token; do note that you should probably not use this scope in many cases, but it's a starting point.